# Which graphql-spring-boot-starter should I choose?

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I'm thinking about adding GraphQL functionalities to my Spring Boot application.

I found there are two artifacts for that.

One is `com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter` and the other is `com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter`.

Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are different Starters (by different teams) providing different features, so there's no right or wrong answer. Here's a quick overview of what I'm aware is available:

The original starter made by the graphql-java team (`com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter`) is now, I believe, defunct and superseded by the Spring GraphQL.

Spring GraphQL (`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` or `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux`) is intended for schema-first development, is relatively simple and not very feature rich, but it's easy to use and works well with other Spring projects (like e.g. WebFlux and Spring Security).

If you want to go code-first (which I argue is [still schema-first](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr#still-schema-first), just better), use [`graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter`](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter), which will generate the GraphQL schema and an end-point for you, with no extra code needed. It's quickest way possible to expose Spring services. There's a sample project [here](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-starter-sample). I'm the main author of that project, so this is a shameless plug, but I honestly believe it's lightyears ahead of other projects in terms of usability. The next version will be based on Spring GraphQL, so it should inherit most/all benefits as well (like e.g. RSocket support, which it currently lacks).

There's also DGS by Netflix (`com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter`). It is also schema-first, has a plenty of features, but is also highly opinionated. I have no first-hand experience with it, but it is well documented, so you should have no problems finding what you need about it.

If you're already using `graphql-java-tools` (maintained by the Kickstart team), you'll likely want to go for `com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter` as they're intended to be used together. I have no clue how actively this project is maintained these days.

Comment: I've used your project before and found it quite easy to use. I wasn't aware of the other projects. I will likely check them out for self-edification. Thanks.

Comment: Also should mention that Netflix offers the DGS framework, which is an abstraction built on top of graphql-java. It was built specifically to be incorporated into Spring :)
https://netflix.github.io/dgs/

Comment: Great library. Really waiting for Spring Boot 3 support. Also proposing out-of-the-box support for protobuf classes. That will be something

Comment: @LewisMunene Upgrading to Spring Boot3 is actually trivial, but I'm trying to rebase the starter onto Spring GraphQL, to avoid maintaining the features already implemented there. As for Protobuf, I've never used it... would you be interested in contributing a module?